# Riemann integral of $x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, integration

[image][image]

Can someone explain me how to do this some. Usually I have seen this been done by dividing the partition to n number of parts. However, I am interested in knowing how it is possible to solve in this method ( source: INTRODUCTIONTO REAL ANALYSIS William F. Trench)

Comment: It might help to include Definition 3.1.1 in the question.

Comment: @GlenO added the definition

Comment: OP should provide more effort.  Write a general Riemann sum (with partition $P$).  Investigate how that is related to the sum $\sum_{j=1}^n d_j^2(x_j-x_{j-1})$.